# Why Chrome is not interpreting my HTML properly and Canary/Safari is?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, html-rendering

I use Chrome as my default navigator and it's been a while that I have to appeal to other browsers (or external tools like [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash)) whenever I need to read some apple documentation because Apple docs menu style is just **broken** for me on Chrome.

[image: Apple docs menu buggy on Chrome makes NSObject docs unreadable]

The unusual thing is that it does not seem to be a CSS incompatibility issue, but seems that the DOM is not being created accordingly to the page's HTML.

This [doc page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113), for example, has this HTML for the menu:

```
<menu id="bashful" type="toolbar">
  <div class="shield"></div>
  <menuitem id="jump_to" class="menu-bar-item closed">
  <span>On This Page</span>
  <div class="chevron"> ... </div>
  <menu type="list" class="details">
      <ul class="list-bullet">
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID106">Mutability of Collections</a>
          </li>

          ... 

      </ul>
  </menu>
</menuitem>

</menu>
```

Ignoring their poor indentation, it is pretty clear that all menu items are inside the `<menuitem>` tag, but when inspecting my chrome elements tab, it does not show that, it shows the `<span>` and `<menu>` tags all outside it, making a lot of CSS selectors rules to stop applying.

Here is how it is being shown on Chrome (buggy)

[image: menuitem tag on Chrome seems to have no children]

and Chrome Canary (works properly),

[image: menuitem tag on Chrome Canary seems to have been parsed properly]

This tests were done with the following browser versions

- Chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) - **breaks**
- Chrome Canary Version 48.0.2528.0 canary (64-bit) - **works**
- Firefox 40.0.3 - **works**
- Safari Version 8.0.8 (10600.8.9) - **works**

First I suspected it to be a simple browser incompatibility issue, so I tried to replicate the problem asking for other people with the same browser to test Apple docs link, but so far I was the only one with this "problem"

I already also tried:

- Disabled all browser extensions
- Disabled/Clear all browser cache
- Compared both browser downloaded HTML and CSS resources but they are identical
- I created [a codepen with just this piece of HTML](http://codepen.io/felipesabino/full/xwdYYp/) and the same issue occurs without all other Apple docs garbage if you want a simple HTML for better analysis
- I checked [`<menuitem>` on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menuitem) and it seems that the `label` attribute is "`Required when a command attribute is not present`", but it this enough to break everything on Chrome? Is Apple using `<menuitem>` for purposes other than the intended in the specification?

Well, does anybody know what might be the cause and what are possible solutions to this annoying issue?

Comment: The page you link to looks OK to me in Chromium 45.0.2454.85. The screen shot looks like something's wrong with the CSS. Are you sure you haven't blocked any of the content or stylesheets, with an ad blocker or something? Edit: oh, wait. Hm. Do you have a user stylesheet in effect?

Comment: According to the official docs, `<menuitem>` doesn't exist. So in theory, browsers can do whatever they like. Edit: Oh, the [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-menuitem-element) does define `<menuitem>` and it says it's a void element. (No end tag.) So there you have it.

Comment: @MrLister "looks OK to me", that's a very annoying thing, why only on my browser? "No end tag" true, I didn't notice it before... "Do you have a user stylesheet in effect?" Not that I know of, is it an extension? because all disabled them all...

Comment: On my version of Chrome, the span is inside the menuitem, so is that something they changed between version 45.0.2454.85 and 45.0.2454.101? But the change is not in v48.0? I couldn't say. I don't know how to search for the change logs in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of Chromium [issue #87553](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87553) "Implement HTMJ5 menu tag".
menuitem parsing is [implemented](https://codereview.chromium.org/443373002/patch/20001/30014) a year ago on [Aug 2014](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87553#c19).

Overall, it seems to be mostly done, but the feature is still "in development" and is [not yet "shipped"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87553#c35), so it is **disabled by default in stable** channel.

When it is not enabled, current stable Chrome (v.45) does not know `menuitem` and parse it as a normal element requiring end tag, instead of as a *content-less* element without end tag according to [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-menuitem-element).
But if you enable the "Experimental Web Platform Features" Chrome flags, [your code](http://codepen.io/felipesabino/full/xwdYYp/) will be parsed correctly.

For now, you can make sure the tags are properly closed.
(Self-closing, as the [spec suggested](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parse-state), does not work for Chrome.)
As long as the menuitem is empty, standard compliance browsers will ignore it and there is no harm done.

P.S. Technically, throwing error and stop is also standard compliance, but no browser really do that.
These are (usually and currently) the only compliance options - die or ignore.

P.S.2 In case it is not clear, as of Oct 2015, `menuitem` element cannot and should not have content, and this part is the same as the Jan 2015 spec.

Comment: I'd forgotten about "Experimental Web Platform Features" but anyways, it  is enabled for me, the funny thing is that the page loads correctly now that I **disabled** it.

Comment: Ok, let's backstep a bit. Firefox 41/42, IE 11, Edge 20, and Chrome 45/46 stable is not up to date with spec. According to current spec, `menuitem` cannot have content, like `hr` or `input`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menuitem), the `<menuitem>` element is an experimental technology and it must be nested as a child element of a `<menu>` element. The element is supposed to provide HTML access to context menus i.e. for right click menus. It has only been officially supported by Firefox. Officially, none of the other browsers support it, which means that it's rendering would be undefined. It may be handled as XML data, or it could be mishandled as some other HTML element that the browser has a definition for, but that's purely speculative.

I find it curious that Apple is using an experimental HTML element that Safari, Apple's own browser, does not officially support. Perhaps they intend to support the element in a future version of Safari, and one of their web devs jumped the gun by using it in a production environment. Even if the element was supported, it still may not function correctly. The current documentation states that there are required attributes (either one of `label` or `command`) which are not used in Apple's code. So the code would still be bad even if it was officially supported.

The short answer is: Apple screwed up, and they need to fix their HTML.

Meanwhile the only "possible solution" for users is to use a different browser. On the developer side, though, there is a nicer solution. If you want to learn about the way that context menus are supposed to be implemented in Chrome, Google has provided an [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) for that purpose.